# Remote printer stopped working or unable to add. Error 0x00002fe3

Tags: printing, windows-7, samba, 19.10, remote

I had a shared printer working on my 19.10 Ubuntu, I used [these advices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101629/windows-7-cant-find-cups-printer-shared-from-ubuntu) to set it up, expecially this one (even because the suggested `system-config-samba` isn't anymore advailable with since 18.04)

```
The trick I had to do using CUPS without samba was to connect to the printer at http://[serverip]:631/printers/[printer-name-here] as opposed to trying to add a local port at the IP address of the server. – ernie Sep 28 '12 at 7:21
```

With all those settings and this simple `http` trick, it worked just fine for months, but for some unknow reason YESTERDAY it stopped. Any time I tried to connect from a(ny) Windows pc it always says it's impossible to reach.

The printer works fine from other Linux or Mac. So I uninstalled and reinstalled the printer in windows control pannel (as suggested in windows support site), the same  error occured.

Oddly enough, after hours of googling, I couldn't find anything about this error...!

I wonder what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky for me today I decided to follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu) and by activating Samba via CLI everything works smoothly.

> Ubuntu print server compatible with Windows (Samba)
>
> If your Ubuntu print server shall be able to work also with Windows
>   clients, you must first make sure that the SAMBA package is installed
>   (e.g. using Synaptic package manager). Then, do a little configuration
>   change to SAMBA. In brief, you must uncomment the following lines in
>   /etc/samba/smb.conf - open terminal and run:
>
> `gksudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`
>
> In the [printers] section:
>
> `browseable = yes`
>   `guest ok = yes`
>
> When done, restart Samba:
>
> `sudo service smbd restart`
>   `sudo service nmbd restart`
>
> There is a [dedicated page in the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-printserver.html) which gives
>   more details.
>
> Also, one would want to allow the following ports through a firewall
>   (ufw for example) via:
>
> `sudo ufw allow 139/tcp`
>   `sudo ufw allow 445/tcp`
>   `sudo ufw allow 137/udp`
>   `sudo ufw allow 138/udp`